# Access to class that intantiated another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Considering I have the following classes:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, origin, value):
        self.origin = origin
        self.origin.b1 = value


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.b1 = 0
        self.b2 = A(self, 1)
        print(self.b1)


b = B()
```

I wish to know if there is any way of avoiding passing the `self` when instancing `class A`, thus getting the origin (`class B`) of the instance from within the `class A` (replacing of course the "`???`"):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.origin = ???
        self.origin.b1 = value


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.b1 = 0
        self.b2 = A(1)
        print(self.b1)


b = B()
```

Comment: No, or at least not in any way I can think of that would be better than just being explicit when instantiating `A`.

Comment: Something about accessing the stack of the call so I can modify the origin class variables

Comment: Circular dependencies usually are better avoided in the first place, and creating them via stack inspection sorcery sounds like trouble waiting to happen.  In your example there's no reason that `B.__init__` couldn't just set `self.b1 = 1` itself rather than having `A.__init__` do it.  If `A` needs to update `B` after instantiation, an observer pattern would be better IMO.

Comment: Of course this is an over simplified example. The idea is that class A is instanced from different classes (class B/C/D) and after performing some logic I want to update a value on each class that instanced the class A

Comment: @kairos That would be an undesirable dependency. What if `A()` is intantiated from something other than a method of the origin object?

Comment: @Barmar, as in my previous comment, A() is instantiated from multiple classes methods. The goal is to generalise a method on A() that updates a common variable (b1) in all the origin classes

Comment: I'm not talking about different classes, I'm talking about instantiating it from something that isn't a class method at all. For instance, the class method might call a regular function to instantiate it. Just pass the origin as a parameter the way you are, rather than trying to find it on the stack.

Comment: @Barmar answering to your question, no. Although it would be nice to verify if the origin type is class so b1 could be set.

Comment: The basic point is that a function should work the same no matter where it's called from. It should get explicit parameters.

Comment: Instead of assigning an attribute, you could require that the origin object have a `set_b()` method. Then if you're passed the wrong type of object an exception would be raised when you do `origin.set_b(value)`

Comment: @Barmar I agree. Although I still don't know how to get the "origin" without explicitly pass the "self"

Comment: You don't, that's what I'm saying. Pass it explictly.